# Are mondevilla adequate to cover balcony?

Tags: houseplants, vines

We have a small balcony that’s covered with a metal grid (something like [this balcony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89Es1.jpg)). We want to cover it with a vine, and the end result  is something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JDkq.jpg).

I was thinking of buying a mondevilla plant for that purpose. I’ve gone to many home depots, plus a few nurseries, and nobody has anything for this purpose, and I just noticed that our local supermarket brought two mondevilla plants.

What do you think? Would it work? This is the [actual mondevila plant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0hWE.jpg) that I would buy.